# How to get position in json file using JS (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

How do I get position in JSON file like

```json
{
  "some-random-id3": {
    "totalxp": 981
  },
  "some-random-id1": {
    "totalxp": 654
  },
  "some-random-id2": {
    "totalxp": 547
  },
  "some-random-id0": {
    "totalxp": 10
  }
}
```

I mean, how can i get if i enter "some-random-id2" -> 3. position or "some-random-id3" -> 1. position

I didnt't tried anything bcs I don't know how to do.

Comment: object properties are not generally positional, but you could look at Object.keys method that will result in an array which should have the keys in the right position - i.e. something like `Object.keys(data).indexOf('some-random-id2')+1` where `data` is the object containing that data read from the JSON file - `+1` since you want a 1-based position rather than the traditional in javascript 0-based

Comment: If you want "positions" maybe an array would make more sense. What would you **do** with the "position" of a nested object? This **seems** like an XY problem.

Comment: I'd personally prefer a 0-based index instead of a 1-based index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no defined way of doing this. As the [JSON documentation](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) quotes (emphasis added):

> An object is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs.

You *might* be able to get away with iterating through `Object.keys()`, but JS objects are also unordered and it is not required to give it to you in the same order every time.

If you're willing to break the JSON specification, then your best bet is to implement your own JSON parser using the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) type, which preserves insertion order. However, this will likely be quite the project. Your other option is to change your data structure. You may want to consider using an array instead (which preserves order), like this:

```
[{
    id: "some-random-id3",
    value: {
      "totalxp": 981
    }
  },
  {
    id: "some-random-id1",
    value: {
      "totalxp": 654
    }
  },
  {
    id: "some-random-id2",
    value: {
      "totalxp": 547
    }
  },
  {
    id: "some-random-id0",
    value: {
      "totalxp": 10
    }
  }
]
```